# How to manipulate list elements in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I'm currently working my way through a project using F#. I'm quite new to functional programming, and while I'm familiar with the idea of list items being immutable, I'm still having a bit of an issue:

I have a list of strings of the format

```
["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]
```

What I would like to do is turn each list element into its own list without the initial comma separated string. The output should look something like this:

```
["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"]
["1"; "2"]
["1"]
```

I've found myriad ways to concatenate list elements and my best guesses thus far (unfolding, or something of the sort) have been fruitless. Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First break the problem down into individual list elements. Start with extracting a list of integers from a string in that format (may I suggest regular expressions). From that point on, it's just a matter of mapping that over each string in the list (List.map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with **the built-in string manipulation API** in .NET. You don't have to make it particular fancy, but it helps to provide some slim, curried Adapters over the `string` API:

```
open System

let removeWhitespace (x : string) = x.Replace(" ", "")

let splitOn (separator : string) (x : string) =
    x.Split([| separator |], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

let trim c (x : string) = x.Trim [| c |]
```

The only slightly tricky step is once you've used `splitOn` to split `"(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"` into `[|"(states"; "1,2,3,4,5))"|]`. Now you have an array with two elements, and you want the second element. You can do this by first taking `Seq.tail` of that array, throwing away the first element, and then taking `Seq.head` of the resulting sequence, giving you the first element of the remaining sequence.

Using these building blocks, you can extract the desired data like this:

```
let result =
    ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]
    |> List.map (
        removeWhitespace
        >> splitOn ",("
        >> Seq.tail
        >> Seq.head
        >> trim ')'
        >> splitOn ","
        >> Array.toList)
```

Result:

```
val result : string list list = [["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"]]
```

The most unsafe part is the `Seq.tail >> Seq.head` combination. It can fail if the input list has fewer than two elements. A safer alternative would be to use something like the following `trySecond` helper function:

```
let trySecond xs =
    match xs |> Seq.truncate 2 |> Seq.toList with
    | [_; second] -> Some second
    | _ -> None
```

Using this function, you can rewrite the data extraction function to be a bit more robust:

```
let result' =
    ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]
    |> List.map (removeWhitespace >> splitOn ",(" >> trySecond)
    |> List.choose id
    |> List.map (trim ')' >> splitOn "," >> Array.toList)
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Not important, but one arguably one should replace `Seq.tail >> Seq.head` with `Seq.item 1` - it's a lot less subtle (but [usefully more] obviously still prone to hitting index of range ) ?

Comment: And as a complete aside, one can write trySecond as `let trySecond =
    function
    | xs when xs |> Seq.length > 1 -> xs |> Seq.item 1 |> Some
    | _ -> None` or `let trySecond =
    function
    | xs when Seq.length xs > 1 -> Seq.item 1 xs |> Some
    | _ -> None` (Though the perf of `Seq.length` could actually be worse vs `Seq.toList` depending on how the latter materializes in the case of a long collection)

Comment: Isn't `x |> List.map fn |> List.choose id` the same as `x |> List.choose fn`?

Comment: @JohannesEgger I think it just might be :)

Comment: Or some distillation of `let rec tryItem index = if index = 0 then Seq.tryHead else tryItem (index-1)`. Hang on ... it's built in:- `let trySecond = Seq.tryItem 1` :)

Answer (score 7):

Just for the fun of it, here's an outline of how to parse the strings using [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/), a parser combinator library.

First, you import some modules:

```
open FParsec.Primitives
open FParsec.CharParsers
```

Then, you can define a parser that will match all strings enclosed by parentheses:

```
let betweenParentheses p s = between (pstring "(") (pstring ")") p s
```

This will match any string enclosed in parentheses, such as `"(42)"`, `"(foo)"`, `"(1,2,3,4,5)"`, etc., depending on the specific parser `p` passed as the first argument.

In order to parse numbers like `"(1,2,3,4,5)"` or `"(1,2)"`, you can combine `betweenParentheses` with FParsec's built-in `sepBy` and `pint32`:

```
let pnumbers s = betweenParentheses (sepBy pint32 (pstring ",")) s
```

`pint32` is a parser of integers, and `sepBy` is a parser that reads a list of values, separated by a string - in this case `","`.

In order to parse an entire 'group' of values, such as `"(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"` or `"(alpha, (1,2))"`, you can again use `betweenParentheses` and `pnumbers`:

```
let pgroup s =
    betweenParentheses
        (manyTill anyChar (pstring ",") >>. spaces >>. pnumbers) s
```

The `manyTill` combination parses any `char` value until it encounters `,`. Next, the `pgroup` parser expects any number of spaces, and then the format defined by `pnumbers`.

Finally, you can define a function that runs the `pgroup` parser on a string:

```
// string -> int32 list option
let parseGroup s =
    match run pgroup s with
    | Success (result, _, _) -> Some result
    | Failure _              -> None
```

Since this function returns an option, you can use `List.choose` to map the strings that can be parsed:

```
> ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]
  |> List.choose parseGroup;;
val it : int32 list list = [[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]; [1; 2]; [1]]
```

Using FParsec is most likely overkill, unless you have some more flexible formatting rules than what can easily be addressed with .NET's standard `string` API.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use Char.IsDigit (at least based on your sample data) like so:

```
open System

// Signature is string -> string list
let getDigits (input : string) =
    input.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.filter Char.IsDigit
    |> Array.map (fun c -> c.ToString())
    |> List.ofArray

// signature is string list -> string list list
let convertToDigits input =
    input
    |> List.map getDigits
```

And testing it out in F# interactive:

```
> let sampleData = ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"];;

val sampleData : string list =
  ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]

> let test = convertToDigits sampleData;;

val test : string list list = [["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"]]
```

*NOTE: If you have more than 1 digit numbers, this will split them into individual elements in the list. If you don't want that you'll have to use regex or string.split or something else.*

Answer (score 4):

As @JWosty suggested, start with a single list item and match it using regular expressions.

```
let text = "(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"
// Match all numbers into group "number"
let pattern = @"^\(\w+,\s*\((?:(?<number>\d+),)*(?<number>\d+)\)$"
let numberMatch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(text, pattern)
let values =
    numberMatch.Groups.["number"].Captures // get all matches from the group
    |> Seq.cast<Capture> // cast each item because regex captures are non-generic (i.e. IEnumerable instead of IEnumerable<'a>)
    |> Seq.map (fun m -> m.Value) // get the matched (string) value for each capture
    |> Seq.map int // parse as int
    |> Seq.toList // listify
```

Doing this for a list of input texts is just a matter of passing this logic to `List.map`.

What I like about this solution is that it doesn't use magic numbers but the core of it is just a regular expression. Also parsing each match as integer is pretty safe because we only match digits.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Luiso's answer, but should avoid exceptions. Note that I  split on `'('` and `')'` so I can isolate the tuple. Then I try to get the tuple only before splitting it on `','` to get the final result. I use pattern matching to avoid exceptions.

```
open System 

let values = ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]


let new_list = values |> List.map(fun i -> i.Split([|'(';')'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                          |> List.map(fun i -> i|> Array.tryItem(1))
                          |> List.map(function x -> match x with
                                                    | Some i -> i.Split(',') |> Array.toList
                                                    | None -> [])

printfn "%A" new_list
```

gives you:

```
[["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should do about you ask:

```
let values = ["(states, (1,2,3,4,5))"; "(alpha, (1,2))"; "(final, (1))"]

let mapper (value:string) = 
    let index = value.IndexOf('(', 2) + 1;
    value.Substring(index, value.Length - index - 2).Split(',') |> Array.toList 

values |> List.map mapper
```

**Output:**

```
val it : string list list = [["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"]]
```

As I see it every item on you original list is a tuple of a `string` and a tuple of `int` of variable size, in any case what the code above does is removing the first *item* of the tuple and then then use the remaining *variable size tuple* (the numbers inside the parens), then call the `.Net string.Split()` function and turns the resulting array to a list. Hope this helps